# Issue with an auto-resizing QStackedLayout

Tags: qt, layout, widget, qt5, qstackedwidget

I try to implement an auto-resizing `QStackedLayout`: what I would like is that the `QStackedLayout` change to the preferred size of the current shown widget. In addition, this `QStackedLayout` contains, among other widgets, ones whose the size can change during runtime (labels displaying a pixmap that can change but when the label in question is not displayed).

Therefore, I have overridden the method `QStackedLayout::sizeHint()` with the following implementation:

```cpp
class StackedLayout : public QStackedLayout
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QStackedLayout::QStackedLayout;
public:
    QSize sizeHint() const override { return currentWidget()->sizeHint(); }
};
```

Then, I call `QWidget::adjustSize()` in the parent widget in order to follow the new "sizeHint" when I change current widget.

However, in reality, the `StackedLayout` instance adjust its size to the one computed with the first size of the pixmap: the `currentWidget()->layout()->sizeHint()` does not seem to be updated when the pixmap (and its size) change. But, what is a bit strange is that when I return a second time to the page, the correct behavior occurs (the `currentWidget()->layout()->sizeHint()` is updated and the widget is correctly resized).

I have firstly thought that I have to force the update by calling `currentWidget()->layout()->update()` just before `QWidget::adjustSize()` but it does not change anything.

Maybe, this issue is due to a misunderstanding of the behavior of `QLayout::sizeHint()`?

Comment: Could you please provide a small program as an example of your problem? I would prefer being able to test it directly, as it's easier to address the problem and fix it. It's hard trying to guess what's wrong from a description.